# Flutter - Listview scroll behind another widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying an appointment view in Flutter. All widgets initially placed ok but when I scroll the listview (list of available hours), the scrolling animation interferes with the element placed on top of it (the calendar). I know that I could use a dropdown but I prefer a list. I have tried several ideas from StackOverflow but still cannot make it work correctly

Images for reference:

[how it looks when started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8QIO.png)

[after start scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM3yN.png)

```
    //simple calender
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hswebapp/days.dart';
import 'package:hswebapp/hours.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Appointment view',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Appointment view'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.twoWeeks;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime? _selectedDay;
  DateTime kFirstDay = DateTime.utc(2021, 1, 15);
  DateTime kLastDay = DateTime.utc(2022, 1, 20);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TableCalendar - Basics'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(

          children: <Widget>[
            daysCalender(),
            Text("Available Hours"),
            const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                  child: 
            AvailableHours(),
                )
          ],
        ) // your column1
      ),
    ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Phone'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Confirm'),
            )
          ],
        ),
        ) 
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to **Column Widget**.

### About Column:

It takes max space vertically until its wrapped with `SizedBox` or `Container` as in your case and given some specific `height`.

So, try giving your `Container` wrapped in `SingleScrollChildView` with some `height` let's say `height = 200.0` and give it shot.

Hopefully this will work :)

Comment: I did worked fine until changed to ListView.builder

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem with Listview.builder. In my case, I am fetching data through FutureBuilder. I will detail how I handled my code below.

```
ListView(
   children: [
     ...
 FutureBuilder(
  controller:controller.fetchPosts(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return const Align(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:Text(
                   "An error occurred while trying to fetch data."),
                    );
      } else (snapshot.hasData) {
               List<PostModel> userItems =
                snapshot.data as List<PostModel>;
                final userPost = userPosts.map((e) => e.toJson());
                final postItem = userPost.toList();
           //then i return a column where the "children" map into my postItem
                r

eturn Column (
                      children: postItem.map<Widget>((post) {
return Text(post['title'])}).toList());
           }})])
```

I hope this will help.